Replacing #define by constexpr char[] where the macro uses another macro
I am updating our codebase to more modern C++. One thing I can do is to replace #define by constexpr statements.
Here's an example where I can't do the substitution:
#define XX "xx"
#define XXYY XX "yy"

After:
constexpr const char XX[] {"xx"};
constexpr const char XXYY[] {XX "yy"}; // invalid

How would I write this in modern C++ without #define? I can use C++20 features.

So, basically how to concatenate 2 constexpr char arrays? However, the proposed solutions are way more complex than simply writing YY XX.

I have no conplete answer, but with C++ it should be posdible to do compile time string view concatenation. That should be at least a good starting point.

just hints: as mentioned above, look how to compile-time concat two strings (they are slightly simpler way I think), and wrap the results within string_views

I guess I need to accept that as an answer and close as a duplicate. Thanks for finding this. I'm not sure I really want to #include a whole new file just for concatenating strings, though. Will discuss with colleagues.

The most "modern" way I found might be to use something like auto yy = std::views::join(std::array{xx, std::string_view{"def"}}). The problem is that you end up with a view over non-contiguous memory, so at some point you need to copy it in a new buffer anyway.

what's the issue with adding standard headers?

@Oersted: not the standard headers, but I need to put the new template somewhere. If I don't want to add up with duplicate code, I'll have something like stringcat.h.

Since C++14, you can do (with #include <string> and using namespace std::string_literals; in effect) const auto XX = "xx"s;  const auto YY = XX + "yy"s;.   Not necessarily compile-time concatenation, but may be of use.

Do it the other way around: constexpr std::string_view XXYY = "xxyy"; constexpr std::string_view XX = XXYY.substr(0,2);.

I changed the strings in order to have a nicer output but it may does the job:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view XX{"left"}; // your first string
constexpr auto YYasArr = []() {
    constexpr std::string_view right{"right"};  // your second string
    std::array<char, XX.length() + right.length() + 1> concat{0};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < XX.length(); ++i) {
        concat[i] = XX[i];
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < right.length(); ++i) {
        concat[i+XX.length()] = right[i];
    }
    return concat;
}();
constexpr std::string_view YY{YYasArr.data()};

int main()
{
    std::cout << YY << '\n';
}

LIVE
I'm going through a intermediate std::array (that you may "hide" inside an implementation namespace) in order to have a persistent storage for the concatenated string.
I Initialize it with a compile-time concatenation and then wrap it inside a std::string_view for easier usage.

from C++20, it can be made shorter, std::copy_n being constexpr:
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view XX{"left"};  // your first string
constexpr auto YYasArr = []() {
    constexpr std::string_view right{"right"};  // your second string
    std::array<char, XX.length() + right.length() + 1> concat{0};
    std::copy_n(std::begin(XX), XX.length(), concat.data());
    std::copy_n(std::begin(right), right.length(), concat.data() + XX.length());
    return concat;
}();
constexpr std::string_view YY{YYasArr.data()};

int main() { std::cout << YY << '\n'; }

LIVE

From comments:

just hints: as mentioned above, look how to compile-time concat two strings (they are slightly simpler way I think), and wrap the results within string_views –
Oersted

What you can try to directly write the concatenated string literal
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view XX = "xx";
constexpr std::string_view XXYY = "xx" "yy";

Live demo

I think the premise is that you don't want to write "xx" twice

@rubenvb is right: I don't want to replicate "xx" because then I need to update it in several places when it needs to be changed. (DRY principle)
